# CKEditor content show in blogs with same styling

Tags: php, jquery, html, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor for blog post it works fine and data saved in database is something like this!"it has img.p,alt,style, and many others tags."
But when each user post his blog stling for each blog is different and i want to show blogs of different users in my blog page.The problem is when i am showing blogs the are not in same style.I want to show my blogs in same styling.
Please help me how i handle this and how i handle this "before saving to database or when retrieing from databse"

Comment: I doubt we will be able to help you if you don't show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to your code: `$content = str_ireplace('\r\n', '', $content);`

So your code should now read:

```
$content = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['content']);
$content = str_ireplace('\r\n', '', $content);
```

I tried it and it works.

Comment: after this how my content looks and its easy to show the content as i wanted..?